# char[] cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, string, char, jpasswordfield

I was trying to set the password entered in a JPasswordField and this error appeared:

```
"Incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to String"

            dts.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(txtSalary.getText()));
            selected=chgAccess.getSelectedIndex();
            dts.setAccess_number((String)chgAccess.getItemAt(selected));
            dts.setLogin(txtLogin.getText());
            //HERE
            dts.setPassword((String)txtPassword.getPassword());
```

How can I fix it?

extra question: then it's supposed to go as a VARCHAR type in my database, will it work? I mean, I have created the spaces in the database for text not for passwords; I didn't find a datatype password in MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

[`getPassword`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword--) returns a `char` array for a good reason - to prevent any lookup of the `String` due to the difficulty in erasing `String` content in memory. Instead I suggest [salting the password](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) and storing the hash in the database.

Answer (score 2):

`getPassword()` returns a `char[]` - it cannot be simply cast to a `java.lang.String`. You could, however, construct a new String for this char array:

```
dts.setPassword(new String(txtPassword.getPassword()));
```

Or, better yet:

```
dts.setPassword(String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()));
```

Comment: It's almost always better to call [String.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char:A-) than `new String`.